# ionic run android is very slow - how to disable lint

Tags: ionic3

After upgrading to Ionic V3.4 the build process is very long.
E.g.

> lint finished in 306.98s

is this normal?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable lint by adding the following to your package.json:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_enable_lint": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed on [ionic-app-scripts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) version 2.0.0 and above.

> Upgrading from 1.x
>
> If you're upgrading directly from 1.3.12 or earlier, make sure you
>   review the changelog for 2.0.0 and follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/releases/tag/v2.0.0).
>   There were some very updates you'll need to make to your app.
>
> If you're customizing the build process and have a dependency that
>   utilized webpack@2.x, it may be best to add an explicit devDependency
>   on webpack@3.1.0 to the project's package.json file. There have been a
>   couple reports of non-standard 3rd party dependencies causing trouble
>   with the webpack version.